What level of certainty does AP News need before calling an election?
According this article, AP News (the Associated Press) doesn't

declare a winner until we are 100% confident that the trailing candidate can't catch up

But clearly this isn't the case. For example, they've been wrong before, like when they called Florida for Gore in 2000. They've even called states when 0% of the votes have came in, when it is certainly not impossible for the trailing candidate to catch up.
So, what level of certainty and confidence does AP News need before calling an election?
The duplicates don't answer my question. My question is what is considered "sufficiently clear", what certainty level. The second duplicate is totally unrelated.

It's a complicated mathematical formula depending on votes cast, votes counted, size of the gap, and probably other factors. I think it can also change over time. Are you looking for the detailed mathematics? AP is probably not going to give it to you.

How many non-swing states went contrary to expectations? Most of these can be called months before Election Day. The precise percentages may vary from expectations, but probably not the overall vote.

https://apnews.com/article/ap-race-calls-presidential-election-winners-0fd480f8ba2f37d0439b76e0c7071413
